# Is it possible that my GFCI receptacle is bad?

Tags: electrical

I have a double wide mobile home. The outside receptacles and the one in master bath do not work. They are GFCI protected but the GFCI is NOT tripped. Is it possible that the GFCI is bad? I think the GFCI in the other bathroom controls these, but how can I know? Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are not supposed to have multiple GFCIs in series. If the outside one is a GFCI typw, it should not be connectd to the bathroom GFCI.

Comment: Note that you *can* have multiple GFCIs on a circuit without having them be "in series", as bib calls it. There's not enough information in the question to know how the wiring is done.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "*the GFCI is NOT tripped*", are you referring to a GFCI breaker or GFCI receptacle? If you're talking about a receptacle, have you checked the breaker/fuse to see if it has tripped/blown?

It's entirely possible that the GFCI is bad. Though it's impossible for anybody to inspect the wiring through the internet, so that's about the most definitive answer anybody will be able to provide. Your best bet would be to contact a local licensed Electrician.

Answer (score 1):

Many people don't realize that it is the inherent in the design of GFCI outlets that the GFCI electronics degrade over time until they fail.  I.e. they have a finite lifespan (I believe on the order of 10 years).

A serious safety issue with older GFCI outlets was that the normal "failure mode" of the GFCI electronics would still deliver electricity at the outlet, just without GFCI protection, and there was no way to find out that the GFCI had failed other than using the test button on the outlet (or a tester at an outlet in the case of a GFCI breaker).

Sometime around 2007 +/- a year or two, the standards were changed requiring that the failure mode be that when the GFCI electronics failed, no power would be delivered to the outlet.

I.e. it could be the expected failure mode of a "modern/ fail-safely" GFCI outlet or breaker.